# Getting Error while converting tensorflow model to tensorflow lite = ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am using a pre-trained keras based and tensorflow based model with yolov2 architecture for potholes detection and I'm getting an error while converting my tensorflow model to tensorflow lite

> Error = ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

I'm using tensorflow 1.3 and keras 2.0.8. This is my code:

```
converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("trained_wts.tflite","wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information.

The error was on the last line, but there was no reference on how to get `marshal` object and how to get `raw_code`.

Comment: Sorry. edited my code up there (last line was typing error)

Comment: https://github.com/jhasuman/potholes-detection
i have downloaded the model from this repository after adding Full_yolo_backend.h5 and trained_wts.h5 the model is predicting well.
but i want to use this model on android device so it needs to be converted in tensorflow lite.
while using the code mentioned above i get the error 
Error = ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)